# Need to find what's causing a number following a caret (^) to produce colors

Tags: colors, lua, formatting

In certain games, such as Quake or Call of Duty, you have been able to change certain re-nameable titles colors by using a caret (^) and then a number, such as ^1 to produce red.

I'm currently working on a public Lua project, and I am trying to find out what's causing this. I have checked the code, but as this happens over multiple games with the same color tied to the same number, I assume this is not something built in into the application, but rather something that's already built in somewhere else. The problem I am having is I can't find where or what it's built into and not having a term for it makes it hard to Google or ask questions about.

Where does this sort of formatting derive from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong: those colors are not part of Lua, but rather are part of the game engines. For example, here's [the code in Quake 3 that does it](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena/blob/dbe4ddb10315479fc00086f08e25d968b4b43c49/code/ui/ui_main.c#L381-L384):

```
        if ( Q_IsColorString( s ) ) {
            memcpy( newColor, g_color_table[ColorIndex(*(s+1))], sizeof( newColor ) );
            newColor[3] = color[3];
            trap_R_SetColor( newColor );
```

It just so happens that a standard for those color codes caught on among games, similar to how the WASD keys being used as arrow keys is common to almost every game.